# What is the best way to get different output for different request methods in django REST API?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, httprequest, serialization

So I have a model having, say, 'field1' and 'field2'  fields.
And I need to have next results depending on the request method was used:

```
http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/app 'someinput'
> {'field1': 'content1'}

http GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/1
> {'field1' : 'content1', 'field2': 'content2'}
```

I guess it has something to do with serializer's `to_representation()` method? but I can't figure out how can I check if the method that triggered `to_representation()` was 'POST' or 'GET'.

Answer (score 4):

It is not very clera if you want to have different output for POST and GET for the same endpoint.

Because as it is written, you have 2 different endpoints for GET and POST in your example - so in that case, you just create 2 different serializers and use it accordingly.

If you have the same endpoint, you can override the following method in your view :

```
def get_serializer_class(self):

    if self.request.method  == 'GET':
        return <your get serializer class>

    return < your post serializer class >
```